# Convert character vector into dataframe

Tags: r

I wanted to practice web scraping and used 'R' and 'rvest' package for it. Now i have a character vector (p_text) of 125 elements and want to convert it into a dataframe. with 25 rows and 5 columns with names q1, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4 .

so element 1,5,10 in column = q1; 2,6,11 in column = opt1; 3,7,12 in column = opt2; and so on.

```
library(dplyr)    
library(rvest)

url <- 'http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/en/test/en-test-sci1.html'

webpage <- read_html(url)

p_text <- webpage %>%
        html_nodes("label") %>%
        html_text()
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to a matrix to arrange things correctly, then to a data frame:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(p_text, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(dat) <- c("q1", "opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4")

str(dat)
## 'data.frame':   25 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ q1  : chr  "Q1: Energy giving foods are " "Q2:Animal fats are categorized as" "Q3: Which is true" "Q4: Trans fats are" ...
##  $ opt1: chr  "Carbohydrates and fats" "saturated fatty acids" "saturated fatty acids are good for health" "unsaturated fats" ...
##  $ opt2: chr  "Carbohydrates and Proteins" "unsaturated fatty acids" "unsaturated fatty acids are harmful for health" "saturated fats" ...
##  $ opt3: chr  "Proteins and fats" "polyunsaturated fatty acids" "unsaturated fatty acids are good for health" "good for health" ...
##  $ opt4: chr  "carbohydrates, fats and proteins" "trans fats" "Animal fats are good for health" "animal fats" ...
```

If you want to clean up the `q1` column, you might want to do:

```
dat$q1 <- sub("^Q\\d{1,2}:[ ]?", "", dat$q1)
```

to remove the leading question numbers, colon, etc.